# Error building chromium 110 - Transforming const to the configured target environment ("es5") is not supported yet

Tags: chromium

The error states this: [ERROR] Transforming const to the configured target environment ("es5") is not supported yet

```
X [ERROR] Transforming const to the configured target environment ("es5") is not supported yet

    gen/third_party/devtools-frontend/src/front_end/entrypoints/formatter_worker/FormatterActions.prebundle.ts:5:7:
      5 Γöé export const enum FormatterActions {
        Γò╡        ~~~~~

  The target environment was set to "es5" here:

    ../../../tsconfig.json:10:14:
      10 Γöé     "target": "es5",
         Γò╡               ~~~~~

X [ERROR] Transforming const to the configured target environment ("es5") is not supported yet

    gen/third_party/devtools-frontend/src/front_end/entrypoints/formatter_worker/FormatterActions.prebundle.ts:13:7:
      13 Γöé export const enum FormattableMediaTypes {
         Γò╡        ~~~~~

  The target environment was set to "es5" here:

    ../../../tsconfig.json:10:14:
      10 Γöé     "target": "es5",
         Γò╡               ~~~~~

X [ERROR] Transforming const to the configured target environment ("es5") is not supported yet

    gen/third_party/devtools-frontend/src/front_end/entrypoints/formatter_worker/FormatterActions.prebundle.ts:23:7:
      23 Γöé export const FORMATTABLE_MEDIA_TYPES: string[] = [
         Γò╡        ~~~~~

  The target environment was set to "es5" here:

    ../../../tsconfig.json:10:14:
      10 Γöé     "target": "es5",
         Γò╡               ~~~~~

X [ERROR] Transforming const to the configured target environment ("es5") is not supported yet

    gen/third_party/devtools-frontend/src/front_end/entrypoints/formatter_worker/FormatterActions.prebundle.ts:43:7:
      43 Γöé export const enum DefinitionKind {
         Γò╡        ~~~~~

  The target environment was set to "es5" here:

    ../../../tsconfig.json:10:14:
      10 Γöé     "target": "es5",
         Γò╡               ~~~~~

[85/51950] CXX obj/third_party/flatbuffers/compiler_files/idl_parser.obj
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
null
```

Any idea what could be the cause?

P.S. The actual build is based on Brave, version 1.48.x to be precise - https://github.com/brave/brave-browser/tree/1.48.x
But anyway, the building error happens in chrome's code...

Answer (score 5):

Meanwhile I was lucky to have discovered an answer and I'm sorry for have creating this question here.

The answer is in Brave's issues on GitHub: https://github.com/brave/brave-browser/issues/21178

Basically change from es5 to esnext in the most toplevel tsconfig.json file (the folder that contains chrome's src folder)